# Z-index "stacking" in creating a shadow

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have the following HTML structure that I'd like to keep nested:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="shadow">Shadow here!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    background: blue;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 200px;

}

.shadow {
    background: lightgrey;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: relative;
    top: 194px;
}
```

Essentially, I want the `div .shadow` to be underneath the `div .parent`. If you look at the rendering at the below link, you can see that part of the parent's blue background goes through the shadow; instead, I'd like the parent element to cover that overlapping part (stacked on top of, I guess you can say):

https://jsfiddle.net/9ya7kb67/

How could I do this? I'm fiddling around with z-index, but that isn't helping.

Comment: Why not use the `box-shadow` properties? Try it here: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 4):

This is simple... give your shadow z-index property negative value like this. You can also manage z-index by giving higher value. Or you can use box-shadow property to make shadow.

```
.parent {
background: blue;
z-index: 2;
height: 200px;

}

.shadow {
background: lightgrey;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0.4;
position: relative;
top: 194px;
}
```

Comment: How come we must use a negative-value there? In my mind, the .parent's z-index is > .shadow's z-index, so it should have stacked regardless of positive or negative values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use box shadow with CSS3 https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 2):

CSS box-shadow works by creating a shadow behind an element. Thus, the element is already on top of the shadow. Here, z-index is not required.

the code:

```
.parent {
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 0 4px light grey;
}
```

is doing the same thing regardless if you include z-index or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the answer you are looking for, but you can always use the CSS property `box-shadow` on your `parent` to get a 'shadowy' effect.

See [this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcww01kb/1/)

You can find box shadow generators online to make your life easier, such as [this one](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

`.shadow` requires a negative `z-index` value as `z-index` is inherited from it's parent and is comparatively displayed. `z-index:0;` gives it the same overall `z-index` the parent has, and as the child was declared after the parent, it is therefore on top. This means that by setting it to `z-index:-1` you are placing the shadow behind the parent.

However, if you simply want a box-shadow I would recommend actually using CSS3 Box Shadows instead of creating additional elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because the shadow is INSIDE of the parent, there is no way to make the parent appear on top of whatever is inside. This is because in CSS a child element inherits the z-index of its parent as a BASE z-index. It can have its own z-index but it can never be less than its parent.

EDIT: Box shadow solution -
https://jsfiddle.net/9ya7kb67/3/

```
.parent {
   background: blue;
   z-index: 2;
   height: 200px;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 0px 4px lightgrey;    
}
```

EDIT2: I stand corrected about it being impossible to put a child below a parent. You CAN actually do this, but that is assuming that the parent does not already have a z-index set. If the parent has a z-index, THEN it is impossible to place it on top of a child.